# “Bang-up” as a noun

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does bang-up mean as a noun? This is where I saw it:

> To him, life is a great big bang-up

This is from the 1967 “Theme From Spider-Man” song. You can find the lyrics [here](https://www.infoplease.com/askeds/spiderman-theme-song).

I searched it, but all I found was an adjective meaning [“first-rate”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bang-up) (from Merriam-Webster), [“very good or excellent”](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/bang-up) (Cambridge) or things like that. No meaning as a noun.

So what does it mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! Interesting question. Thanks for finding the lyrics. Brought back loads of memories. Based on the context and history of the character it is easy to see that a bang-up just means a fight. If you recall the cartoon (I never missed it) that is about all they did. He could have no close friends and no room for other interests. In his case a fight could be pretty fun since he's never going to lose, what with spider powers and Stan Lee (bless his heart) on your side.